# Background working of the Object.equals method in the collection?

Tags: java, collections, equals

```
    HashSet hs = new HashSet();

    hs.add(10);
    hs.add("sum");
    hs.add(10);
    hs.add(12.3d);

    System.out.println(hs);
```

---

1) In the above code how does java know that when the second object is passed, it needs not check it with the first one. And how does it know that when the third object(i.e 10) is passed it needs to call the overridden .equals method of the Integer class to check first and third object.

2)If it calls the .equals method of the object class then both integers have different instances so both should be added, but this isn't the case.

I need the background working of the .equals method in the collection!

Comment: Dont use raw types HashSet<String>

Answer (score 0):

`equals` doesn't take reference of instances in account under all circumstances. It is basically a custom implementation that depends on the type of the object and by default just compare references. You can imagine `Integer::equals` as

```
boolean equals(Object other) { 
  boolean isSameType = other instanceof Integer;
  return isSameType && ((Integer)other).value == value;
}
```

So two `Integer` instances with the same value will be considered equal. In addition you are dealing with and `HashSet<T>` so you must take `int hashCode()` into account, which should be consistent with `equals` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your `HashSet` isn't parameterized with a generic, so you're right in thinking that it will be treated as a `HashSet<Object>`.

However, when the comparisons between the element to add and the current elements of the set are made, the *object type's* `equals` and `hashCode` methods are taken into account. Thus, when you add `10` and `10` again, it will use `Integer.equals` to determine equality at execution time.

`HashSet<Object>` deals only with the *reference type* `Object`, meaning that the compiler demands that all objects in the `HashSet` are an instance of or extend `Object` (which all objects are, of course). This has nothing to do with the execution of methods, however, whose behaviors are defined by the *actual object's* type.

Summarily, if I define:

```
Object obj = new Integer(10);
```

And I call:

```
obj.equals(anotherObj);
```

The compiler will ensure that the *reference type* (`Object`) has a method called `equals`, and at runtime the behavior of the *object type* (`Integer`) is executed.

Answer (score 0):

uniqueness in Set,internally in java  through **HashMap** . Whenever you create an object of HashSet it will create an object of HashMap. As we know in HashMap each key is unique. If key is not null then , it will call hashfunction on the key object i.e. key.hashCode(), so after key.hashCode() returns hashValue, it looks like - **int hash = hash(hashValue)** , and now ,it applies returned hashValue into its own hashing function.
final  **hashvalue is used to find the bucket location** at which the Entry object is stored . Entry object stores in the bucket like this (hash,key,value,bucketindex). So we traverse through linked list, **comparing keys in each entries using keys.equals() until it return true.**  Then the corresponding entry object Value is returned, i.e  if two objects hash value is same the equals method will be called to verify it is same or not. If not then object will find it's place in the bucket(link list).